# Diagram of survival times

Tags: diagrams

excuse me, could someone tell me how to convert this to latex? I cannot find similar examples. Thank you.

[image: diagram of survival times]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What does it correspond to, mathematically?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome. To actuarial science.

Comment: If you have the equation of the oblique line, it is easy to reproduce with LaTeX graphic package (pstricks, TiKZ,…). The specific background of the upper part would be more tricky, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun your drawing it is not possible to reproduce or convert the same: here there are a `LaTeX` code created himself with Mathcha - https://www.mathcha.io/editor:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}      
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (421,55.5) -- (153,173) -- (421,173) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 232; green, 232; blue, 232 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (420.83,29) -- (420.83,55.5) -- (153,173) -- (153,31) -- cycle ;
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (153,55.5) -- (420.67,55.5) ;
% Text Node
\draw (241,77.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\fcolorbox{white}{white}{0.6}$};
% Text Node
\draw (155,176.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (139,157.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (131,46.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$40$};
% Text Node
\draw (131,20.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$50$};
% Text Node
\draw (152,7.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$T_{y}$};
% Text Node
\draw (422.67,176.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$40$};
% Text Node
\draw (425,158.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$T_{x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\textsf{Diagram of survival \ldots}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]